# Compare function for sorting vector of strings (each string is a number) C++

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I'm trying to use the following comparison function for sorting a `vector<string>` , in which each string is a number (possibly large number upto 10^100). But I'm getting a debug assertion failure error in VS2010.

```
bool compareNumberStrings (const string &a, const string &b) 
{
    if (a.length () < b.length ()) 
        return true;

    if (a.length () == b.length ()) 
    {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<a.length() && a[i] == b[i]; i++);

        if (i != a.length ()) 
            return a[i] < b[i];
        else 
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `stringstream` to convert the string into a number and then do a direct comparison on those numbers?

Comment: Take a look to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ and implement your own comparator.

Comment: Care to share which assertion fires?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure numbers represented by the string can be 10^100, will it still work?

Comment: Have you considered arbitrary precision number library?

Comment: You might need to serialize into a larger type, maybe. :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're returning `true` when the strings are completely equal. This is a violation of the requirements: the function must define a strict weak ordering, i.e. `f(x, x)` must return `false`. Your function returns `true`, and the library might well contain a check that this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could stop storing numbers in strings and use a big number library (e.g. [GMP MP](http://gmplib.org/))